# jupyterlab how to apply tags without having to edit cell metadata

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter-lab. When I have to edit a cell tag currently I go to Notebook tools - Advanced Tools - Cell Metadata to add a tag like

```
{
    "tags": [
        "noinput"
    ]
}
```

That is a bit tedious. Is there a quicker way to do this or is there a way to set it for all cells at once?